# A better way to URL Rewrite this .htaccess

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, ssl, url-rewriting

Could there be a better way of doing this I wonder. It is doing the following:

A) routing mydomain.uk to www.mydomain.uk

B) routing anything non http to https://www.mydomain.uk

I dont use linux based servers much so im sure there is a better way of doing this. End result should be any base url should end up at https://www.mydomain.uk

Heres the code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.uk\/" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OR`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mydomain.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

The rule `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.uk$` can also be more restrictive and catch any host which is not `www.mydomain.uk`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but to my untrained linux eyes I was wondering if there was any difference in what the two different(ish) answers were doing and if one was a better way.

Comment: Both are correct. @anubhava is a "redirect everything that doesn't match" approach, mine is a "redirect only if matches".

Comment: I generally suggest to use his approach, except in the case the rule is placed in a virtual host that can potentially be served with different hostnames, and you only care about redirecting the not-www to www. This may be the case with some shared hosting services that maps subdomains in a folder within the main domain (such as CPanel was used to do).

Comment: Thanks @Simone-Carletti I think both can be marked as an answer however as I am using yours, I will choose that one.

Answer (score 2):

These 2 rules can be easily combined into one as this one:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mydomain.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but to my untrained linux eyes I was wondering if there was any difference in what the two different(ish) answers were doing and if one was a better way.

Comment: Well if you don't have multiple domain names pointing to same `DocumentRoot` then this rule eliminated need to hardcode host-name twice in the rule. (Even this single hardcoding can be eliminated if you want).